# Circle with two Strokes on GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps

For visualizing the action on geofence entry and exit, I want two display to different borders/strokes in the radius of the geofence.

```
googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng).radius(radius-4).strokeColor(entryColor).strokeWidth(8));
googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(latLng).radius(radius+4).strokeColor(exitColor).strokeWidth(8));
```

This will not work, since radius is in meter and strokeWidth in pixel(?). One could calculate the pixel per meter, but this would change for every zoom.

Using a (transparent) fill is messy when geofences with different colors overlap.

Answer (score 0):

`Circle` is a special class of polygon that's there to simplify construction. Even with using polygons, you can only set 1 stroke width/color.

The suggestion I can come up with is similar to yours, using 2 circles with different radius, color and stroke values.